# hadoop's start-dfs not creating datanode on the slave

Tags: hadoop, ssh, hadoop-yarn, master-slave

I am trying to set a Hadoop cluster over two nodes. `start-dfs.sh` on my master node is opening a window and shortly after the window closes, and when i execute `start-dfs` it logs namenode is correctly launched, but datanode is not and logs the following :

```
    Problem binding to [slave-VM1:9005] java.net.BindException: Cannot assign requested address: bind; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/BindException
```

I have set

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -P ''
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

(and also set `adminstrators_authorized_keys` file with the right public key) (also ssh user@remotemachine is working and gives access to the slave)

Here's my full Hadoop configuration set on both master and slave machines (Windows):

```
hdfs-site.xml : 
<configuration>
    <property>
            <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
            <value>/C:/Hadoop/hadoop-3.2.2/data/namenode</value>
    </property>
<property>
  <name>dfs.datanode.https.address</name>
  <value>slaveVM1:50475</value>
</property>
    <property>
            <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
            <value>/C:/Hadoop/hadoop-3.2.2/data/datanode</value>
    </property>

    <property>
            <name>dfs.replication</name>
            <value>2</value>
    </property>
</configuration>

core-site.xml : 


<configuration>
 <property>
   <name>dfs.datanode.http.address</name>
   <value>slaveVM1:9005</value>
 </property>
 <property>
            <name>fs.default.name</name>
            <value>hdfs://masterVM2:9000</value>
  </property>
  <property>
            <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
            <value>/C:/Hadoop/hadoop-3.2.2/hadoopTmp</value>
   </property>
   <property>
            <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
            <value>hdfs://masterVM2:8020</value>
   </property>
</configuration>
```

mapred-site.xml

```
<configuration>
<property>
         <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
         <value>masterVM2:9001</value>
   </property>
    <property>
        <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
        <value>yarn</value>
    </property>
    <property> 
        <name>mapreduce.application.classpath</name>
        <value>%HADOOP_HOME%/share/hadoop/mapreduce/*,%HADOOP_HOME%/share/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/*,%HADOOP_HOME%/share/hadoop/common/*,%HADOOP_HOME%/share/hadoop/common/lib/*,%HADOOP_HOME%/share/hadoop/yarn/*,%HADOOP_HOME%/share/hadoop/yarn/lib/*,%HADOOP_HOME%/share/hadoop/hdfs/*,%HADOOP_HOME%/share/hadoop/hdfs/lib/*</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

yarn-site.xml

```
   <configuration>
    <property>
            <name>yarn.acl.enable</name>
            <value>0</value>
    </property>

    <property>
            <name>yarn.resourcemanager.hostname</name>
            <value>master</value>
    </property>

    <property>
            <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
            <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

PS : i am adminstrator on both machines, and i set `HADOOP_CONF_DIR` `C:\Hadoop\hadoop-3.2.2\etc\hadoop`
I also set the slave IP in `hadoop_conf_dir` `slaves` file.

PS : if i remove the code :

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.datanode.https.address</name>
  <value>slave:50475</value>
</property>
```

from `hdfs-site.xml`

Then both datanote and namenode launch on the master node.

hosts :

```
*.*.*.* slaveVM1
*.*.*.* masterVM2
```

*.*.*.* are the IPs of the respective machines, all other entries are commented out

Comment: You should report if you are using windows, mac or linux.  If you are using any special setup.  I see that you have 'C:' references so it's likely your running windows but don't want to assume

Comment: yes i'm on Windows server 19

Comment: Could you add your host file entries?

Comment: see my update, thx

Comment: Can you clarify:
if you remove:
<property>
  <name>dfs.datanode.https.address</name>
  <value>slave:50475</value>
</property> 

or

<property>
  <name>dfs.datanode.https.address</name>
  <value>slaveVM1:50475</value>
</property>
or 
<property>
   <name>dfs.datanode.http.address</name>
   <value>slaveVM1:9005</value>
 </property>
and it works?

Comment: Also don't mix IP addresses and server names. " I also set the slave IP in hadoop_conf_dir slaves file."  use all server names. --> slaveVM1
You will only feel pain if you keep using ip address with Hadoop.  update the slaves with "slaveVM1"

Comment: i tried to include the `dfs.datanode.https.address` in my configuration so that some sort of connection with the slave is established, but it turns out it does not work that way. So i removed the code you mention in the comment and then the master node runs datanode and namenode when i did `start-dfs` (which i don't want : datanode should be running on the slave) it was like hadoop was running standalone one node mode

Comment: for the second comment, HADOOP/conf/workers is the file where you put the IP of the slaves (on the master node). OK for the suggestion

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens

> BindException: Cannot assign requested address: bind;

when the port in use. Meaning maybe it's the application was already started, or was started previously and didn't shut down properly or another applicaiton is using that port.  Try rebooting, (as a heavy handed but reasonably effective way of clearing ports).

Comment: no i checked by changing the port (i did that many times while checking availability of chosen port) but that exception was still showing no matter what port number i used

Comment: it doesn't look like the master is trying to connect to the slave whatsoever what are the configs involved in exposing the slave to the master except the `workers` file  ?